# How does while take parametral conditions?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple code:

```
compare()
{
        n=$#
        echo "Refference number: "
        read x

        while [ $n -gt 0 ]
                do
                if [ $1 -gt $x ]
                        then
                        echo "A greater number was found: " $1
                fi
                shift
        done
}
```

In this manner the script doesnt work well. I get an infinite loop with error on the while line.

If I replace that while line with `while [ $# -gt 0 ]` everything works fine.

Why is this happening? Isnt $n=$# ?
I use CentOS 7.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You seem to be expecting the expansion `$n` to be lazily evaluated. Technically, that's possible using arithmetic context, but it would be a pretty confusing approach. Why don't you just keep referring to the literal `$#`?

Comment: I just needed a variable that keeps the $# and if i could use it in while, I said "Why not?". I dont really understood what you have said with the lazily evaluation. :/

Comment: @Marko [Lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) is when the programming language defers evaluating the final result until it has to know the current value. In this case, the question is "does `$n` equal `$#` any time you evaluate `$n`, or does it only equal `$#` at a point in time?"

Comment: `$#` change every time you call `shift`; `$n` would be the value that doesn't change.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the additional info! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$#` directly in the while loop. It will naturally change each time you call `shift`.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    ...
    shift
done
```

Otherwise, you'll have to update `$n` yourself each iteration.

```
while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do
    ...
    shift
    ((--n))
done
```

Assigning `n=$#` makes `$n` equal to `$#` at that point in time. It doesn't mean it is automatically updated when `$#` changes.

Comment: I see now the problem, thank you!
One more thing though to be sure:
If I will put n=$# after the shift command, it should be fine with while [ "$n" -gt 0 ] also, isnt it?

Comment: I'd still stick with just using `$#` throughout, but yes, that would work.

Comment: I understand that is a better practice with the $#, its clear now. The question was just to see if i got it right. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

`$n` contains a copy of the value of `$#` at the time it was assigned.  Nothing changes `$n` thereafter, so the loop either runs not at all or runs continuously.

When you use `$#` in the loop condition, the `shift` reduces the number of arguments by one, and therefore `$#` decreases, and the loop terminates.

Comment: When will the shift command stop decrementing the $# ? What happens if I still call it after I'll have no arguments left?

Comment: Most likely, the value of `$#` remains at zero and the empty argument list remains empty.  Funny, I don't ever remember testing to see what happens; it didn't seem interesting. — _[…time passes…]_ — There's no error, and `$#` remains at zero, and there continue to be no arguments.